# How to Calculate duration 01-01-2016 to 31-01-2016 . get answer 1 month in PHP

Tags: php, date, duration

Calculate between two Dates duration  in PHP

Example :

Start Date : `01-01-2016`

End Date   : `31-01-2016`

I get Answer is 30 days but I want result is 1 month

More Examples:

01-01-2016 to 31-01-2016  = 1 month

01-02-2016 to 29-02-2016 =1 month

01-03-2016 to 31-03-2016 =1 month

show on ..

Comment: It's not 1 month. It's only 30 days.

Comment: Please post the code you have used

Comment: i need result is 1 month

Example 01-01-2016 is Start Date and 31-01-2016 is end date

01 to 31 January this pried is one month

Comment: my code is

$date1 = "2016-01-01";

$date2 = "2016-01-31";

$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));


$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));

printf("%d years, %d months, %d days\n", $years, $months, $days);

Comment: What if start date and end date are not first date and last date of the month?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$date1 = '2000-01-20';
$date2 = '2000-02-20';

$ts1 = strtotime($date1);
$ts2 = strtotime($date2);

$year1 = date('Y', $ts1);
$year2 = date('Y', $ts2);

$month1 = date('m', $ts1);
$month2 = date('m', $ts2);

echo $diff = (($year2 - $year1) * 12) + ($month2 - $month1);
?>
```

I think this will help you.

Comment: this one also not working . It display in days only.I want in month according to calender.i.e if  01-01-2016 to 31-01-2016  = 1 month, 01-02-2016 to 29-02-2016 =1 month

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I tried.

Find the first and last day of the month of first date and compare them with the given dates. If they matches it prints "1 month" else it prints the number of days like "n days".

```
$date1 = "2016-02-01";
$date2 = "2016-02-29";

$output = "";
if ($date1 == date("Y-m-01", strtotime($date1)) && $date2 == date("Y-m-t", strtotime($date1))) {
    $output = "1 month";
} else {
    $output = ((strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1)) / 86400 + 1) . " days";
}

echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class shahjadclass {




    public function getduration($postdate) {


        /*  $postdate is the date where the post was created  */

$assigned_time = date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");       
$d1 = new DateTime($assigned_time);
$d2 = new DateTime($postdate);
$interval = $d2->diff($d1);
$datestring='';
if($interval->y>0){
$datestring=$interval->format('%y Years ago') ;
}elseif ($interval->m>0) {
$datestring=$interval->format('%m Months ago') ;
}elseif ($interval->d>0) {
$datestring=$interval->format('%d Days ago') ;                                        
}elseif ($interval->h>0) {
$datestring=$interval->format('%h Hours ago') ;                          
}elseif($interval->i>0){
$datestring=$interval->format('%i Min ago') ;  
}else{
$datestring=$interval->format('%s Sec ago') ;
}

 return $datestring;  
    }





}
```

**

> Usage

```
require_once('shahjadclass.php');
 $myfunctions = new shahjadclass();
```

> To get Output

```
 $datestring=$myfunctions->getduration('createdon');
```

**